# Java Print array on the same line with separator

Tags: java, arrays, csv, line, separator

I have a class that is reading a specific column from a file and inserting it in a an array. I would like to have that array printed on the same line with a comma separator.

**Below is my code:**

```
public static void getArray(int Column, File path, String Splitter) throws IOException
{
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path.toPath(), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII); 

    for (String line : lines) 
    { 
        String[] array = line.split(Splitter); 

         //Will return all elemetns on the same line but without any separation, i need some kind of separation 
         // if i use System.out.print(array[Column]+" ,");
         // i will always get a , at the end of the line
        System.out.print(array[Column]);

    }
}


getArray(3, file, "|");
```

**Current output is:**

> abcdefg

**Desired output is:**

> a,b,c,d,e,g

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) collector.

to join the elements of the array with the delimiter `,`.

```
String result = Arrays.stream(array)
                      .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

to join the characters of a given element within the array with the delimiter `,`.

```
String result = Arrays.stream(array[Column].split(""))
                      .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

another variant of joining the characters of a given element within the array with the delimiter `,`:

```
String result = array[Column].chars()
                             .mapToObj( i -> String.valueOf((char)i))
                             .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: hey, that printed out all of the file i am reading from with a , separation. I needed that separation only on the column i have selected.

Comment: Then change `Arrays.stream(array)` to `Arrays.stream(array[Column].toCharArray())`

Comment: Yes, I tried the newly proposed modification, here is the  error is got on stream : The method stream(T[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (char[])

Comment: @Lothar, yes i want for the specific column but here is what got printed:
`0,.,6,30,.,6,41,.,9,01,.,7,11,.,0,11,.,2,61,.,5,31,.,0,00,.,5,90,.,9,54`

Comment: @Lothar close but not quite, as there is no overload in the Arrays class that accepts a `char[]` which makes sense as there is no `CharStream`. nevertheless, I've updated my answer to accommodate OP's comment.

Comment: @Joe yet another variant `String result = Pattern.compile("")
                .splitAsStream(array[Column])
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without streams (in Java 8+, for `String.join`):

```
String.join(",", array)
```

But you can also do it with a plain old loop:

```
String delim = "";
for (String part : array) {
```

Comment: you can just do `String.join(",", array);`